# Can't invoke a method from an object in a hashtable

Tags: java

so all I'm trying to do is create this object and then store it and others like it in a hashtable and then use ones of its methods later.  But when I try and get the object and use its method I get an error.

My Code:

```
D_Object obj;
Hashtable player_table;

obj = new D_Object("pikachu",pikachu,PLAYER_X,PLAYER_Y,PIKA_WIDTH,PIKA_HEIGHT,PIKA_OFFSETX,PIKA_OFFSETY,PLAYER_SPEED);

player_table.put(obj.getObjNum(),obj);
```

....then later I try and use the objects method getObjNum() and it gives me an error

```
for(int i=1;i<=obj.getNumObjs();i++){
    if(player_table.get(i).getObjNum() != obj.getObjNum()){
```

....

the error is as follows:

```
appletGameExample.java:319: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getObjNum()
location: class java.lang.Object
```

It gives the same error for any time I try and use the methods from this object

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

Use it as `Hashtable<int, D_Object>`

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't specify what kind of objects the `Hashtable` holds, it retrieves them as `Object` by default (the class that everything `extend`s).  An `Object` doesn't have the methods you're trying to invoke on it.  You will need to perform type-casting upon accessing them, or specify what the `Hashtable` holds, like so:

`Hashtable<String, D_Object> player_table = new Hashtable<String, D_Object>();`

Answer (score 0):

```
((D_Object)player_table.get(i)).getObjNum()
```